# Why does this Harvard-MIT tournament's solution not double count?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a problem from the 2010 Harvard-MIT Mathematics Tournament:

"""Manya has a stack of 85 = 1 + 4 + 16 + 64 blocks comprised of 4 layers (the kth layer from the top
has 4k−1 blocks; see the diagram below). Each block rests on 4 smaller blocks, each with dimensions
half those of the larger block. Laura removes blocks one at a time from this stack, removing only blocks
that currently have no blocks on top of them. Find the number of ways Laura can remove precisely 5
blocks from Manya’s stack (the order in which they are removed matters)."""

[image]

And the reference solution is as follows:

Each time Laura removes a block, 4 additional blocks are exposed, increasing the
total number of exposed blocks by 3. She removes 5 blocks, for a total of 1 · 4 · 7 · 10 · 13 ways. However,
the stack originally only has 4 layers, so we must subtract the cases where removing a block on the
bottom layer does not expose any new blocks. There are 1 · 4 · 4 · 4 · 4 = 256 of these (the last factor of
4 is from the 4 blocks that we counted as being exposed, but were not actually). So our final answer
is 1 · 4 · 7 · 10 · 13 − 1 · 4 · 4 · 4 · 4 = 3384.

However, I think the above solution has double counting. For simplicity lets say we just want to remove 3 blocks. Based on the proposed solution there are 1.4.7 = 28 different ways to do so. But there are in fact C(4, 2) + 4 * 4 = 22 ways, because there is only one way to remove the first block, and then there are C(4, 2) ways to remove the next two blocks from different next layer blocks, and 4 * 4 ways to remove them from the same next layer block.

Comment: (the order in which they are removed matters)

Comment: There are $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ (note that "the order in which they are removed matters") ways to remove two blocks from the second layer and (as you say correctly) $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ ways to remove two blocks from different layers. Hence as order matters, no double counting.

Comment: Ah silly mistake, Thank you guys!